# Android - Fatal Signal 11 when stopping and resetting camera after recording video

Tags: android, android-camera, segmentation-fault, android-mediarecorder

I currently have an app that I am trying to record video, with the following method to initialize the camera:

```
private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.unlock();
    }

    if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile);

    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    initSuccess = true;
}
```

When I try to stop the camera or when `surfaceDestroyed` is called, I call the following method:

```
private void resetCamera()  {
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    mMediaRecorder.release();
    mCamera.release();

    mCamera = null;

    try {
        initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, somewhere in this code I am getting a Fatal Signal 11 error.  Apparently the code is trying to illegally access a portion of memory.

I was wondering, how would I get around this error?

Here is a Logcat dump from when I start recording the video to when I stop recording:

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1309K, 27% free 7434K/10168K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
I/dalvikvm: Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
I/dalvikvm: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/dalvikvm: JIT_INFO: ME Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
I/dalvikvm: The trace provoked a spill.
I/dalvikvm: Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1415K, 27% free 7438K/10168K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 13774 (arch.treadmill3)
```

Comment: Post the full log of the error (I know it isn't a java trace, but sometimes the other info in it is useful).

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After mMediaRecorder.release(); you have to write mMediaRecorder = null; because release() method seems to have few bugs.
Like this:

```
if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
    }
```